# Dock Ability arrows editable

Tags: c#, wpf, docking, syncfusion

Hi I was wondering is there a way to only edit the Dock Ability Arrows on the Dock Guide for a docking manager using syncfusion for wpf? I can edit the complete style of the docking manager but I only want the ability to edit the arrows as I have the theme in a specific way but need the arrows only to be different is this possible at all? And if so how can I access it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this you need to edit the Drag Provider Templates below is some XAML example for anyone who has a similar problem or was curious as to how to do it

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:Syncfusion="http://schemas.syncfusion.com/wpf"
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">

<!-- Control template for TopDragProvider -->
<ControlTemplate x:Key="TopDragProviderTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
    <Image Name="Img" Width="29" Height="32" Syncfusion:DockPreviewManagerVS2005.ProviderAction="GlobalTop" Source="pack://application:,,,/Syncfusion.Tools.WPF;component/Framework/DockingManager/Resources/DockPreviewVS2005GlobalTop.png" />
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsSideButtonActive, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Syncfusion:DockPreviewMainButtonVS2005}}}" Value="true">
            <Setter TargetName="Img" Property="Source" Value="pack://application:,,,/Syncfusion.Tools.WPF;component/Framework/DockingManager/Resources/DockPreviewVS2005GlobalTopOver.png"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>

<!-- Control template for LeftDragProvider -->
<ControlTemplate x:Key="LeftDragProviderTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
    <Image Name="Img" Width="32" Height="29" Syncfusion:DockPreviewManagerVS2005.ProviderAction="GlobalLeft" Source="pack://application:,,,/Syncfusion.Tools.WPF;component/Framework/DockingManager/Resources/DockPreviewVS2005GlobalLeft.png" />
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsSideButtonActive, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Syncfusion:DockPreviewMainButtonVS2005}}}" Value="true">
            <Setter TargetName="Img" Property="Source" Value="pack://application:,,,/Syncfusion.Tools.WPF;component/Framework/DockingManager/Resources/DockPreviewVS2005GlobalLeftOver.png"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>

<!-- Control template for RightDragProvider -->
<ControlTemplate x:Key="RightDragProviderTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
    <Image Name="Img" Width="32" Height="29" Syncfusion:DockPreviewManagerVS2005.ProviderAction="GlobalRight" Source="pack://application:,,,/Syncfusion.Tools.WPF;component/Framework/DockingManager/Resources/DockPreviewVS2005GlobalRight.png" />
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsSideButtonActive, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Syncfusion:DockPreviewMainButtonVS2005}}}" Value="true">
            <Setter TargetName="Img" Property="Source" Value="pack://application:,,,/Syncfusion.Tools.WPF;component/Framework/DockingManager/Resources/DockPreviewVS2005GlobalRightOver.png"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>

<!-- Control template for BottomDragProvider -->
<ControlTemplate x:Key="BottomDragProviderTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
    <Image Name="Img" Width="29" Height="32" Syncfusion:DockPreviewManagerVS2005.ProviderAction="GlobalBottom" Source="pack://application:,,,/Syncfusion.Tools.WPF;component/Framework/DockingManager/Resources/DockPreviewVS2005GlobalBottom.png" />
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsSideButtonActive, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Syncfusion:DockPreviewMainButtonVS2005}}}" Value="true">
            <Setter TargetName="Img" Property="Source" Value="pack://application:,,,/Syncfusion.Tools.WPF;component/Framework/DockingManager/Resources/DockPreviewVS2005GlobalBottomOver.png"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```